# Label a subplot based on the ylabel's x coordinate and title's y co-coordinate

Tags: python, matplotlib

**How could I set a label for a plot ('1' and '2' in the screenshot below) based on ylabel's x coordinate and title's y co-coordinate?**

Use case: I would like such alignment to automate the formatting of multipanel figures where the ylabels are aligned first using `fig.align_ylabels`. Then would be very likely that the corner labels of the subplots would be aligned too.

[image]

**This is what I tried but did not work:**

**For `x`**, I tried `ax.yaxis.get_label_position()` which provided 'left' as output. This is not what I am looking for. Then I tried `ax.yaxis.get_label().get_position()`. The output looked to be in terms of the axes fractions.

**For `y`**, I used `ax.title.get_position()[1]`, which provided location which is in terms of the axis fractions.

Here's the test code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,axs=plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=[6,3])
for i,ax in enumerate(axs):
    ax.set(title='title',xlabel='xlabel',ylabel='ylabel',xlim=[0,10],ylim=[0,10])
    x,y=ax.yaxis.get_label().get_position()[0],ax.title.get_position()[1]
    ax.text(x=x,y=y,s=i+1,ha='left',va='center',transform=ax.transAxes)
    print(f"for subplot#{i+1} coordinates of the label, x,y={x},{y}",)
## outputs
#for subplot#1 coordinates of the label, x,y=0,1.0
#for subplot#2 coordinates of the label, x,y=0,1.0
```

A possible solution may lie in converting the coordinates from one to another, but I am not experienced enough in that to intuitively figure that out. But I hope somebody would.

[image]

Comment: I believe the value you are already looking for can be found with the [reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#data-coordinates) ax.transData.transform() to find which pixel is on the figure. I think you can use the annotation function to make the xy coordinate reference a pixel.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried but could not get the labels at the position where I wanted, especially if the widths of the subplots are unequal. y coordinate is correct but, x is off, which is of the y-axis instead of the ylabel. I wonder if there any other way to get the x-position of the y label.

Comment: I used the following code to get the respective positions.
With that data, I annotated the string. However, I could not explain the basis for the adjusted values, so I did not answer the question.

Comment: `xy = ax.transData.transform([ax.yaxis.get_label().get_position()[0],ax.title.get_position()[1]]);offset = 55;ax.annotate(i+1, (xy[0]-offset, (fig_height*fig.dpi)-xy[1]+offset), xycoords='figure pixels');`