# How can I get the x coordinate of a ylabel in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this example:

```
from numpy import linspace, sin
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, ylabel, gcf, text

x = linspace(0, 1)
y = x ** 2
plot(x, y)
ylabel("test")
```

I now want to place some text *approximately* like "abc" in this figure:

[image: A cut out version of the plot that would be generated by the above code, showing parts of the left y-axix and the y-axis label. The text "abc" is added in red below the y-axis label so that their left margins with respect to the figure coincide.]

For this, I need the x coordinate of the y-label, or at least approximately. I tried the following:

```
xd, _ = pyplot.gca().yaxis.get_label().get_transform().transform((0, 0))
```

But it seems that `xd` is now always 0 in display coordinates. That is clearly not correct. Furthermore, if I want to transform it back to figure coordinates to display the text:

```
x, _ = gcf().transFigure.inverted().transform_point((xd, 0))
text(0, 0.5, "abcdefg", transform=gcf().transFigure)
```

I get this:

[image: A cut out version of the plot that would be generated by the above code, showing parts of the left y-axix and the y-axis label. The text "abcdefg" has a smaller left margin with respect to the figure and therefore runs over the y-axis label.]

So clearly, the x coordinate is not correct.

Comment: See the comments at [Label a subplot based on the ylabel's x coordinate and title's y co-coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75404525/label-a-subplot-based-on-the-ylabels-x-coordinate-and-titles-y-co-coordinate)

Comment: @JohanC That also does not give the correct coordinates. I also would have to choose `offset` instead of having an automated way to get the position.

Comment: My answer to this question may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77121817/what-kind-of-text-object-are-axis-labels/77122190#77122190

Comment: @RuthC Indeed, that seems to be what's going on here.

Comment: I don't understand what the ylabel has to do with the question - I would just do `ax.text(-0.04, 0.3, 'Boo', transform=ax.transAxes, ha='right')` in axes co-ordinates

Comment: @JodyKlymak It defines the left margin of the text.

Comment: So you want the left margin of your annotation to line up with the left margin of the ylabel for some reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What kind of Text object are axis labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77121817/what-kind-of-text-object-are-axis-labels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the discussion into an answer:

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylabel("test")
# draw the elements
fig.draw_without_rendering()
# get the position of the ylabel and transform it to coordinates
pos_pixel = ax.yaxis.label.get_tightbbox()
x_coord = ax.transData.inverted().transform((pos_pixel.x0, pos_pixel.y0))[0]
plt.text(x_coord, 0.42, "abc", color="red")
plt.show()
```